# Effiecient way to multiply a pandas dataframe column at index n with another column in same dataframe at index n-k

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following pandas dataframe

```
idx day col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4
 1   1    a    A     4     5
 2   1    b    B     5     8
 3   1    a    B     4     11
 4   2    a    A     3     8 
 5   2    b    B     3     6
 6   2    a    B     4     11
 7   3    b    B     5     1
```

Now leaving the rows with `day=1`, I want to multiply `col_3` values of remaining days with `col_4` values of `day` before, such that both rows have same `col_1` and `col_2` values and replace the value in `col_3`. For example, In the dataframe for row 4 (`idx=4`), I want to go back a before such that I have same values for `col_1` and `col_2`, which will be row with `idx=1`. Now, I replace current value of `col_3` in row 4 with (old value of `col_3` in `idx=4`)*(`col_4` value in `idx=1`), which is `3*5=15`. I want to continue this to the end of the dataframe. So My new dataframe will look like this,

```
    idx day col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4
     1   1    a    A     4     5
     2   1    b    B     5     8
     3   1    a    B     4     11
     4   2    a    A     15    8 
     5   2    b    B     24    6
     6   2    a    B     44    11
     7   3    b    B     30    1
```

For every `day` we will have all the three combinations of `col_1` and `col_2`. The way which I use to achieve this is using a for loop like this,

```
for i in range(3,data_frame.shape[0]):
    day_ = data_frame['day'].iloc[i]
    col1 = data_frame['col_1'].iloc[i]
    col2 = data_frame['col_2'].iloc[i]
    col3 = data_frame['col_3'].iloc[i]
    f = data_frame.loc[(data_frame['col_1']==col1)&(data_frame['col_2']==col2)&(data_frame['day']==day_-1),'col_4'].values[0]
    data_frame.loc[(data_frame['col_1']==col1)&(data_frame['col_2']==col2)&(data_frame['day']==day_),'col_3']=f*col3
```

This code is very inefficient because the dataframe I'm working with has thousands of rows and multiple columns that I need to match before performing the operation. Also in my case I should go back to 7 days instead of going back 1 day as shown in the example. I assume there should be an efficient way to do this using `groupby` and `loc` operations but I couldn't come up with it. Is there an efficient to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Some logic with `groupby` and `shift`

```
df['new'] = df.groupby(['col_1','col_2'])['col_4'].shift().fillna(1).mul(df['col_3'])
0     4.0
1     5.0
2     4.0
3    15.0
4    24.0
5    44.0
6    30.0
dtype: float64
```